# Print array in JSON using Java JsonObjectBuilder

Tags: java, arrays, json, double

I am developing a simple project in Java to output a JSON file. The JSON file will include geo-location data which will have to be printed in this exact format:

```
 "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -1.072925602, 
            51.27924757
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
```

Meaning each file will have two key fields coordinates and type, where coordinates will have the latitude and longitude data.

Now I am developing this using the standard JsonObjectBuilder and I really cannot find a way how to print the latitude and longitude data in that exact format; btw I cannot print it as a string.

Is there a way how to print an array of type double using the JsonObjectBuilder?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

Just print is as string and in the future, when you will need, you can always parse that string to double like that:

```
double x = Double.parseDouble(string);
```

where "string" is longitude (or latitude) as string

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I am using this project to simulate the communication (via JSON) between two systems and that is the format they are using. If I send it as a string, it will not work.

I'm pretty sure there must be a way to do this because it seems to me that it is a simple requirement. Other libraries like the GSON can do this, however I'd rather use this library if possible as I have been using it for quite a while now.